# Remove inconsistent acronyms in strings using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I would like to remove all acronyms, even those that are written inconsistently. For instance, in the list below (`text`), some of the acronyms miss an opening or a closing bracket, thus I would like the remove those too. I am only able to remove those with both closing brackets.

How can I adapt my current re expression so that it does not only focus on upper case chars with 2 surrounding brackets?

```
import re

text = ['Spain (ES)', 'Netherlands (NL .', 'United States (USA.', 'Russia RU)']  

for string in text:
  cleaned_acronyms = re.sub(r'\([A-Z]*\)', '', string) #remove uppercase chars with ( ). 
  print(cleaned_acronyms)

#current output
>>> Spain 
>>> Netherlands (NL .
>>> United States (USA.
>>> Russia RU)
```

**Desired output:**

```
>>> Spain
>>> Netherlands
>>> United States
>>> Russia
```

Comment: `r'\([A-Z]*\)?'`?

Comment: that works to some extent, not the for the RU) acronym. Thanks for the '?' tip though!

Comment: You could match them both ways around till the end of the string, and replace with an empty string `\s*(?:\([A-Z]{2,}\)?|[A-Z]{2,}\)).*` https://regex101.com/r/jYWXji/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the uppercase chars between parenthesis with either one per side, followed by the rest of the line.

```
\s*(?:\([A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]{2,}\)).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5ulAw/1)

For example

```
import re

text = ['Spain (ES)', 'Netherlands (NL .', 'United States (USA.', 'Russia RU)']

for string in text:
    cleaned_acronyms = re.sub(r'\s*(?:\([A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]{2,}\)).*', '', string)
    print(cleaned_acronyms)
```

Output

```
Spain
Netherlands
United States
Russia
```

Answer (score 2):

You might get along with

```
 \(?\b[A-Z.]{2,3}\b.+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vPUhSL/1/).